# Duality form of $L^q$ norm, without assumption that $\int fg$ defined?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration

The following theorem is found, for example, in the Real Analysis books by Folland, by Yeh, and (in a slightly different form) by Royden.

**Theorem.** Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. 
Let $S_0$ be the space of all measurable simple functions which vanish outside a set of finite measure. Let $g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function.  Assume $\{ x: g(x) \neq 0 \}$ is $\sigma$-finite. Assume $fg \in L^1$ for all $f \in S_0$. 
Let $1 \leq p,q \leq \infty$ be conjugate exponents (i.e., $p^{-1} + q^{-1} = 1$). 
Then
$$
\|g\|_q = \sup\left\{ \left|\int fg \right| : f \in S_0, \, \|f\|_p=1 \right\}. 
$$

For brevity below, denote the supremum by $M_q(g)$.

Notice that we do not assume $g \in L^q$.

My question is about the assumption that $fg \in L^1$ for all $f \in S_0$.

**Question.** Can we delete the assumption that $fg \in L^1$ for all $f \in S_0$?

First, it seems that its fine if we only require $\int fg$ to be defined (meaning it could be finite or infinite). This is because if $\int fg = \pm \infty$ for some $f$, then the supremum $M_q(g)$ equals $+\infty$, so $\|g\|_q \leq M_q(g)$ holds trivially. The reverse inequality is just Holder.

But what if we don't have the assumption that $\int fg$ is defined for all $f \in S_0$? 
I see that without that assumption, the set whose supremum we are taking doesn't really make sense since the integral may not be defined. But could we drop the hypothesis and instead introduce some convention in the definition of the set, like (for example) we only consider $f$ such that $\int fg$ is defined? Is it possible to have $\|g\|_q = \infty$ but $M_q(g) < \infty$ when we adopt a convention like the one described above. In the extreme case, is it possible to $\|g\|_q = \infty$ but $\int fg$ undefined for every $f \in S_0$?

Cross-Posted from MSE after several days of inactivity: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3606890/95800

Comment: I answered on Math.SE because I think it's a better fit over there.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's fair. But I wonder if the question would have been answered if I hadn't tried it over here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

More a comment than an answer, really:

If you want to characterize $L^q$ functions, I don't really understand why you want to remove this assumption? For, if your function $g$ really does belong to $L^q$ (which would be the conclusion of the "alternative theorem" anyway), then indeed $fg\in L^1$ for all $f\in S_0$ (the latter being bounded and supported on a sets $E_f$ of finite measure so $gf\in(L^q(E_f)\otimes L^\infty(E_f))\subset L^1(E_f)$ with the obvious abuse of notations).

If the conclusion of the theorem you're hoping for is the same dual characterization $\|g\|_{L^q}=(\dots)$ then you might as well include this as an assumption, right?

An auxiliary comment: If $ fg\in L^1$ for all $f\in S_0$ then clearly $g\in L^1_{loc}$. So I guess an alternative theorem is "if $g\in L^1_{loc}$" then $\|g\|_{L^q}=\sup(\dots...)$

Comment: But I don't only want to characterize L^q functions. Indeed, the proof is easy if $g \in L^q$. The point of this theorem (at least to me) is that you can use it to prove that a given function $g$ belongs to $L^q$ by estimating $\int fg$ for appropriate $f \in L^p$

Comment: yes yes of course I get that, but still my comment applies: even if what you're going after is the very fact that $g\in L^q$, and not the computation of the norm itself, my argument remains the same. If you want to conclude that $g\in L^q$ then in the end of the day necessarily the "assumption" that $fg\in L^1$ for all $f\in S_0$ must hold a posteriori, right?

Comment: by the way: can you think of a measurable function such that it is not true that {$fg\in L^1$ for all $f\in S_0$} ?? by my auxiliary comment such a function cannot be in $L^1_{loc}$, so it must be quite nasty (all the more if you want to conclude that $g\in L^q$ !!!!)

Comment: That's true. Fair point.

Comment: of course I get it that removing this hypothesis allows you to check one less thing, but in fact the assumption is EQUIVALENT to being in $L^1_{loc}$, so it should be straightforward for any $g$ defined in any reasonable way